# How to create an ethereum accounts for my own token using node js web3

Tags: web3js, accounts, tokens, nodejs

I have created my own token and now I want to create accounts for clients where they stock tokens using node js express.But I have no idea how to generate accounts' address !
Can anyone help me please even with useful linkS to start :)
Here is the  code that I have written (the code compiled well but no address is returned)

```
var mytoken= MyContract.at(contractAddress);

//accounts creation
   var options = {
      host: '/home/yosra/Bureau/mynetwork/ResponsableRH/geth.ipc',
      ipc:true,
      personal: true, 
      admin: false,
      debug: false

          };

   var web3 = web3_extended.create(options);

   var newaccount=web3.personal.newAccount("password",function(error,result){

       if(!error){
          console.log(result);
                 }
    });
```